# Is onChange or onClick deprecated in html GlobalEventHandlers?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I see it used on websites so I"m unsure. Can I use OnChange and onClick inside my html ? I'm a little confused, I thought javascript was deprecated in html ? However, I think these two actions are part of DOM GlobalEventHandlers ? I think jquery uses it alot so I should be fine ?

```
<select id="select" class="button" onChange=getValue()>
```

I think what is meant by not using js in html is

```
<p javascript:code> </p>
```

Well, I got an error but I think it has to do with the way chrome extension works. I'll have to look into this:

Refused to execute inline event handler because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' blob: filesystem: chrome-extension-resource:". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-...'), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution.

Comment: Sorry, I'm a little confused as to what your exact question is. Do you think you could clarify? Are you asking about Chrome extensions?

Comment: @BurningLights I was asking if I could use onClick and onChange in my html or is it deprecated ?

Comment: According to MDN (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Event_attributes) event attributes should be avoided. But, I couldn't find anything about them being deprecated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Sounds like you're writing a Google Chrome extension. You cannot use **any** inline event handlers (i.e, `onEvent` attributes) under the security model used for extension pages*. All events must be set up from Javascript code, e.g.

```
document.getElementById("select").addEventListener("change", getValue);
```

or, if you're using jQuery:

```
$("#select").change(getValue);
```

---

*: Specifically, [the Content Security policy for Chrome extensions](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy).

Comment: Aww ok, I didn't want to add an event listener change for just one select box but I guess Ill have to do that :) . Now, if I wasn't making a chrome extension is this legal in the online world for webpages ? using onEvent attributes ? or I can just add a small submit button and use the same event handler click that I have for my other buttons.

Comment: @ritchie "Legal" is a tough word to nail down. Anyways, though, inline event handlers are still supported by browsers, but are not generally recommended.

Answer (score 2):

You can use onclick in html and you have to write a javascript function that onclick will do. Using onclick does not required jQuery and you can just do pure javascript.

HTML

```
<button onclick="foo()">Do something</button>
<p id="foo"></p>
```

JS

```
function foo() {
    document.getElementById("foo").innerHTML = "Foo";
}
```